# Is it possible to make a background thread run faster?

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch, rubymotion

I am using RubyMotion and have a calendar implemented using [CKCalendarView](https://github.com/jaykz52/CKCalendar) and I have the following code highlighting days on which events occur.

The following method is called from `layoutSubviews`

```
def calendarDidLayoutSubviews(calendar)
  _events_array = []
  if self.events
    self.events.reverse.each do |ev|
      mdy = ev.date.month_date_year
      _events_array <<  mdy unless _events_array.include?(mdy)
    end
  end

  Dispatch::Queue.main.async do
    today = NSDate.date.month_date_year

    if calendar.dateButtons && calendar.dateButtons.length > 0
      calendar.dateButtons.each do |db|
        db.backgroundColor = "f4f2ee".to_color
        if db.date && db.date >= calendar.minimumDate && db.date <= calendar.maximumDate
          if _events_array && _events_array.length > 0
            db.setTitleColor("c7c3bb".to_color, forState:UIControlStateNormal)
            db.backgroundColor = "f4f2ee".to_color
            if _events_array.include?(db.date.month_date_year)
              db.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor, forState:UIControlStateNormal)
              db.backgroundColor = "9ebf6c".to_color
              _events_array.delete(db.date.month_date_year)
            end
          end
        end
        if db.date && db.date.month_date_year == today
          if calendar.minimumDate <= db.date && calendar.maximumDate >= db.date
            db.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor, forState:UIControlStateNormal)
          else
            db.setTitleColor("f4f2ee".to_color, forState:UIControlStateNormal)
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

As it is, this freezes the UI for a .5 - 1.5s when drawing. If I move it in to a background thread, it takes 4 or 5 times as long to draw, but doesn't freeze the UI.

**Question:** Is there a way to give the background thread a higher priority, or a way to incrementally draw and highlight the dateButtons so that it doesn't look like nothing is happening in the half dozen seconds it takes to draw(when not in the main thread)?

Comment: idk rubymotion but you should ALWAYS do drawing in the main thread. do your logic in the background, then have a callback in the main thread to do that drawing

Comment: So would performance take a hit if I called the main thread for the drawing inside the loop?

Comment: Can you explain in pseudo what's going on here? How big are these arrays? I'm not familiar with either if you could explain what a datebutton is and how many there are. Do they represent days in a month? I'll look at the documentation a little

Comment: Basically, I am looping through a list of days in a calendar (29 - 31), and highlighting the dateButton if an event occurs on that day. the number of events being anywhere from 0 - 25 usually -there is no enforced upper limit.

Comment: @SilasJ: Performance doesn't matter when you're drawing: It HAS to be done on the main thread, else horrible things can happen (accessing the drawing cache from two threads, graphics not rendering, general UIKit awfulness).

Comment: @CodaFi - I see. Is there a way to do this without freezing the UI?

Comment: Do your dispatch_async work on non-UI objects, then update the UI from a nested dispatch.  If you're freezing the UI, it means something is going wrong on the main thread, so start looking for blocking operations and get rid of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method I posted was getting called in the main thread, so I switched it to be called in a background thread, and then called the main thread for all drawing operations inside my loop.

```
def calendarDidLayoutSubviews(calendar)
   _events_array = []
  if self.events
    self.events.reverse.each do |ev|
      mdy = ev.date.month_date_year
      _events_array <<  mdy unless _events_array.include?(mdy)
    end
  end

  today = NSDate.date.month_date_year

  if calendar.dateButtons && calendar.dateButtons.length > 0
    calendar.dateButtons.each do |db|
      Dispatch::Queue.main.async do
        db.backgroundColor = "f4f2ee".to_color
      end
      if db.date && db.date >= calendar.minimumDate && db.date <= calendar.maximumDate
        if _events_array && _events_array.length > 0
          Dispatch::Queue.main.async do
            db.setTitleColor("c7c3bb".to_color, forState:UIControlStateNormal)
            db.backgroundColor = "f4f2ee".to_color
          end
          if _events_array.include?(db.date.month_date_year)
            Dispatch::Queue.main.async do
              db.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor, forState:UIControlStateNormal)
              db.backgroundColor = "9ebf6c".to_color
            end
            _events_array.delete(db.date.month_date_year)
          end
        end
      end
      if db.date && db.date.month_date_year == today
        if calendar.minimumDate <= db.date && calendar.maximumDate >= db.date
          Dispatch::Queue.main.async do
            db.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor, forState:UIControlStateNormal)
          end
        else
          Dispatch::Queue.main.async do
            db.setTitleColor("f4f2ee".to_color, forState:UIControlStateNormal)
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the way to go (I have no clue what the overhead is for calling the main thread so many times in one loop), but it works.